# impacts of AUTOTRACE TRACEONLY

Tags: oracle11g, performance-testing, sqlplus

On oracle 11g, what is the impact of executing a query with `SET AUTOTRACE TRACEONLY` compare to the execution of the query itself?

Is there any risk to run it on a production environment? Could a deadlock occurs for example or any other problem?

Comment: `traceonly` will still execute the query in the background but simply not fetch the results - so it has the same risks as running the statement without autotrace

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name maybe you could write that as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a_horse_with_no_name 
traceonly will still execute the query in the background but simply not fetch the results - so it has the same risks as running the statement without autotrace